# Rails: Mapping a Date from form parameters into ActiveModel object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5

I have a filter-class which includes ActiveModel and consists of two dates:

```
class MealFilter
  include ActiveModel::Model

  attribute :day_from, Date
  attribute :day_to, Date
end
```

That model is rendered into a form as following:

```
  <%= form_for(@filter) do |f| %>
      <div class="form-group form-group--date">
        <%= f.label :day_from %>
        <%= f.date_select :day_from %>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group form-group--date">
        <%= f.label :day_to %>
        <%= f.date_select :day_to %>
      </div>
  <% end %>
```

The problem is now, when the form gets submitted, it sends this parameters to the controller:

```
{"utf8"=>"✓", "meal_filter"=>{"day_from(1i)"=>"2016", "day_from(2i)"=>"1", "day_from(3i)"=>"29", "day_to(1i)"=>"2016", "day_to(2i)"=>"1", "day_to(3i)"=>"30"}, "commit"=>"Filter"}
```

I extract the values via Controller parameters:

```
def meal_filter_params
  if params.has_key? :meal_filter
    params.require(:meal_filter).permit(:day_from, :day_to)
  end
end
```

if I now assign the `params[:meal_filter]` to my `MealFilter` class with `@filter = MealFilter.new(meal_filter_params)`, my date fields are not updated correctly. It seams that the **1i, 2i, 3i** parts are not correctly assigned to the dates.

However, this works fine if used an `ActiveRecord` class.

Do I miss some include? Does anyone know, where this magic mapping is implemented if not in `ActiveModel::Model`?

Comment: What is `meal_filter_params`? Are you getting a strong parameters warning in your Rails log perhaps?

Comment: It´s a method on the controller that returns only the permitted meal_filter params...I updated the description to clarify that. A Parameter warnings does not exist in my console.

Comment: And what do you mean by "not updated correctly"? How how you checking that it's updated?

Comment: The `date_from` and `date_to` properties on my filter are not set. The are just `nil` if I call `MealFilter.new(meal_filter_params)`

Comment: Is there a redirect after the update before rendering the filter?

Comment: nope. But i found a solution for this problem. See my answer. Nevertheless - thanks for your support!

Answer (score 3):

I came across this issue while upgrading an app from Rails 3.2 to 5.0

How I sorted it out is as follows:

In Rails 5+

```rb
class MealFilter
  include ActiveModel::Model
  include ActiveModel::Attributes
  include ActiveRecord::AttributeAssignment

  attribute :day_from, :date
end
```

or alternatively

```rb
  class MealFilter
    include ActiveRecord::AttributeAssignment

    attr_reader :day_from

    def initialize(attributes = {})
      self.attributes = attributes
    end

    def day_from=(value)
      @day_from = ActiveRecord::Type::Date.new.cast(value)
    end
  end
```

In Rails 4.2

```rb
  class MealFilter
    include ActiveRecord::AttributeAssignment

    attr_accessor :day_from

    def initialize(attributes = {})
      self.attributes = attributes
    end

    def type_for_attribute(name)
      case name
      when "day_from" then ActiveRecord::Type::Date.new
      end
    end
  end
```

Then you can do:

```rb
  attributes  = { "day_from(3i)" => "1", "day_from(2i)" => "9", "day_from(1i)" => "2020" }
  meal_filter = MealFilter.new(attributes)
  meal_filter.day_from
  # => Tue, 01 Sep 2020
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, found a solution.
What I needed was the MultiparameterAssignment which is actually implemented in ActiveRecord but not in ActiveModel.

As far as I can see, there is an open pull request (https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/8189) that should resolve this issue.

But in the meantime, some clever guy wrote a module that can be included into the model: https://gist.github.com/mhuggins/6c3d343fd800cf88f28e

All you need to do is to include the concern and define a `class_for_attribute` method that returns the class where your attribute should be mapped to - in my case `Date`.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply access the 1i, 2i and 3i parameters from the date_select helper and combine them to make new Date in a before_validation callback:

```
class DateOfBirth
  include ActiveModel::Model
  include ActiveModel::Attributes
  include ActiveModel::Validations::Callbacks

  attribute :date_of_birth, :date
  attribute "date_of_birth(3i)", :string
  attribute "date_of_birth(2i)", :string
  attribute "date_of_birth(1i)", :string

  before_validation :make_a_date

  validates :date_of_birth, presence: { message: "You need to enter a valid date of birth" }

  def make_a_date
    year = self.send("date_of_birth(1i)").to_i 
    month = self.send("date_of_birth(2i)").to_i
    day = self.send("date_of_birth(3i)").to_i

    begin # catch invalid dates, e.g. 31 Feb
      self.date_of_birth = Date.new(year, month, day)
    rescue ArgumentError
      return
    end
  end
end
```